# calculate antilog in python? np.exp / math.exp doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have an array of log values temp= [4,4.05......9]
These are actually from 10^4 to 10^9
for example, log(10^4)=4 and so on
I need to take the antilog of temp array to get these numbers from 10^4 to 10^9 but when I calculate np.exp(6.89) it gives me 991
So how to take antilog correctly?

`enter code here`Eve_gradual_mr24_23=np.exp(np.mean(new_q3[340:350]))

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.exp10.html

Answer (score 2):

`np.exp` is the exponential in base e. If you want the exponential in base 10, you could use `scipy.special.exp10` or simply `10.0**your_array`

Comment: Nitpick: use `10.0**your_array` in preference to `10**your_array`. The latter fails with a `ValueError` if `your_array` is of integer dtype and contains negative values.