# Calculate the inverse log10 of positve and negative numbers of a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, logarithm

So I have a pandas data-frame (‘df_forecast’) that consists of two columns, the timestamp (‘DI_Interval’) and a list of values that are in Log10 format (‘RRP_SA’), as shown in the image included below.
[image: Pandas Dataframe]

I want to determine the Log10 inverse of the ‘RRP_SA’ column and create this as a new column called ‘RRPForecast’, which I have done with the following code:

```
# Calculate the inverse log10 of the number and create as new column
df_forecast["RRPForecast"] = 10**( df_forecast["RRP_SA"])
```

The issue is that the original ‘RRP_SA’ column has some negative numbers in it which also need to be converted back to their original number format. Could someone please help me edit my code so that it has the flexibility to do the log 10 inverse of both positive and negative numbers.

***Reason for having positive and negative log10 numbers:*** I am performing a forecast of electricity prices for the spot market, in order to train my Machine Learning model, both the negative and positive electricity prices are converted into log10 format so that the model can be trained faster. However, I need the prices back in normal number format so that I can make comparisons with the actual electricity prices, thank you.

Comment: it is already capable of doing that, for e.g. `10**(-5)`

Comment: In addition to the generic exponentiation suggested by anther comment, you may also consider invoking the `exp10` function of a suitable library, e.g. `scipy.special.exp10()`. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580907/calculate-antilog-in-python-np-exp-math-exp-doesnt-work